# Aggregate Unwind Mongo Object

Tags: mongodb

I have a document in MongoDB that has a view attribute of type object:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5adc896dbc05c93a8a0fc9"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-02-06T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "partner_id" : 36,
    "partner_user_id" : 163,
    "partner_user_name" : "Adriano",
    "view" : {
        "webbundlecontrollersecurecontroller" : 1,
        "webbundlecontrollerclientcontroller" : 1,
        "webbundlecontrollerordercontroller" : 6
    }
}
```

I need to execute a query that would return something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5adc896dbc05c93a8a0fc9"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-02-06T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "partner_id" : 36,
    "partner_user_id" : 163,
    "partner_user_name" : "Adriano",
    "controller" : "webbundlecontrollersecurecontroller"
    "total": 1
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5adc896dbc05c93a8a0fc9"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-02-06T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "partner_id" : 36,
    "partner_user_id" : 163,
    "partner_user_name" : "Adriano",
    "controller" : "webbundlecontrollerclientcontroller"
    "total": 1
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5adc896dbc05c93a8a0fc9"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-02-06T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "partner_id" : 36,
    "partner_user_id" : 163,
    "partner_user_name" : "Adriano",
    "controller" : "webbundlecontrollerordercontroller"
    "total": 6
}
```

Basically convert the view Object attribute on the first document as 3 new objects. I tried using aggregate with unwind, but not sure how is the best query to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to query using objectToArray to convert the object, then unwind and build my final query.

```
db.pmm_page_view.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project: {
            date: 1,
            partner_id: 1,
            partner_user_id: 1,
            partner_user_name: 1, 
            view: { $objectToArray: "$view" }
         }
      },
      { $unwind: "$view" },
      {
         $project: {
            date: 1,
            partner_id: 1,
            partner_user_id: 1,
            partner_user_name: 1, 
            controller: "$view.k",
            total: "$view.v"
         }
      }
   ]
)
```